# Exported GeoPackage from R not drawing in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, r, geopackage, sf

I am trying to export multiple layers of point data from R as a single GeoPackage. The code works fine (included below), however when I try and load the resulting GeoPackage into ArcMap (10.6) I get the following pop-up:

[image: ArcMap pop-up]

Followed by this error:

[image: ArcMap Error]

I've not had this issue before when exporting GeoPackages from R and loading them in ArcMap and am not sure what is causing these problems (especially when it loads into QGIS fine). I have tried both `writeOGR` and `st_write` to export as a GeoPackage but encounter the same issue with both.

```
require("raster")
require("sf")

Data1 <- read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", "1RHAqtsPXgD5rH-ppIu7cLblHXyXzv_39"))
Data2 <- read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", "1Mzi6A6L_cXOrT9dTbm8gggGdtNQnZYkY"))
Data3 <- read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", "1ZzYiFIJxs2Coeb4kBNsWhmiF5NZDUhrL"))

Data1_Coords <- cbind(Easting = as.numeric(as.character(Data1$OSEAST1M)),Northing = as.numeric(as.character(Data1$OSNRTH1M)))
Data2_Coords <- cbind(Easting = as.numeric(as.character(Data2$OSEAST1M)),Northing = as.numeric(as.character(Data2$OSNRTH1M)))
Data3_Coords <- cbind(Easting = as.numeric(as.character(Data3$OSEAST1M)),Northing = as.numeric(as.character(Data3$OSNRTH1M)))

Data1_Points <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(Data1_Coords, data = Data1, proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))
Data2_Points <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(Data2_Coords, data = Data2, proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))
Data3_Points <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(Data3_Coords, data = Data3, proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))

Data1_Points_ST <- st_as_sf(Data1_Points)
Data2_Points_ST <- st_as_sf(Data2_Points)
Data3_Points_ST <- st_as_sf(Data3_Points)

st_write(Data1_Points_ST, "DataGPKG.gpkg", "Data1")
st_write(Data2_Points_ST, "DataGPKG.gpkg", "Data2", update = TRUE)
st_write(Data3_Points_ST, "DataGPKG.gpkg", "Data3", update = TRUE)
```