# ArcGIS GeoPackage ArcMap Drawing Error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, sf, geopackage, layers-failed-to-draw

I am trying to understand the meaning of this error. I created spatial data using the `sf` package in `R` and wrote out the data as a `GeoPackage` (i.e. a `.gpkg`). However, whenever I add the data into ArcMap, I receive the following error.

[image]

Unfortunately, my reproducible R example works and my real example still does not, thus something must be wrong with my code. And I cannot figure out what it is. The real code is too long and cannot be copied here.

The weird thing is that when I write the data in `R` out as a `shapefile`, there is no error and the data is correctly spatially referenced, etc. What does this error mean? And why would it produce as a `.gpkg` and not as a `.shp`?

A similar error message was seen [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288583/exported-geopackage-from-r-not-drawing-in-arcmap), but it is a little different.

Comment: Maybe you have some invalid field name? When you export to shapefile the field names are truncated and maybe the error is being truncated away

Comment: Which version of ArcMap? Unlikely; but maybe an older version not understanding the contents of the package?

Comment: @KHibma, ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1.

Comment: @BERA, I think that maybe an issue as one of my fields is called "Unique.ID". Can geopackage file types not accept "."s in field names?

Comment: Dont know. Or ArcMap cant handle the dot in the field name. Rename it before creating the gpkg

Comment: @BERA, thank you for the help! It has a worked. I replaced a "." with "_" and my geopackage could be read into ArcMap. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarification, @BERA's comment was correct. There were invalid field names. In my R Script, I simply added the below line of code to remove `.`'s and to replace them with `_`'s. Assuming your dataframe or sf object is called `df`:

```
# Remove dots from column (field) names and replace with _
colnames(df) <- gsub("\\.", "_", colnames(df))
```

should do it.